# dynamic textview with touch listener

Tags: textview, ontouchlistener

> hello i am in new android , i need to develop one program like number of
>   sentence over the screen. each sentence have word and each and every
>   word have click event or touch event . every word should perform one
>   action show toast on that x and y coordinates where user click.
>
> how to do that dynamic way ? i tryout to creating dynamic text view
>   but the touch event not giving perfect x and y point .
>
> Please any one have idea about this please show me some code snippet .
>
> Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of using the text view you could do it with a simple button.But the thing is to make the button transparent so that it appears like TEXT View. Use this in your code for button view in your xml android:background="@android:color/transparent"

Comment: i get answer i need use getRawX() method for x position and set layout params to each textview which generate by own code